# Set variable in jinja

Tags: python, templates, variables, variable-assignment, jinja2

I would like to know how can I set a variable with another variable in jinja. I will explain, I have got a submenu and I would like show which link is active. I tried this:

```
{% set active_link = {{recordtype}} -%}
```

where recordtype is a variable given for my template.

Comment: Folks landing here from Google: you will probably be primarily interested in the [official docs on the `set` tag](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/latest/templates/#assignments), rather than the specific syntax mistake made by the asker here or how to fix it, which is what the top answers here and at the linked duplicate address.

Answer (score 682):

`{{ }}` tells the template to *print* the value, this won't work in expressions like you're trying to do.  Instead, use the `{% set %}` template tag and then assign the value the same way you would in normal python code.

```
{% set testing = 'it worked' %}
{% set another = testing %}
{{ another }}
```

Result:

```
it worked
```

Comment: if my variable is dict what now {% set dict.key = 'test' %} don't work

Comment: A deleted answer also included this link, which serves as supplementary information to this answer: http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/tricks/#highlighting-active-menu-items

Comment: can we create a global jinja variable and use it throughout the html file in which we embed the jinja variable? @Soviut

Comment: To further illustrate by extending this example:
`{% set another = testing + " flawlessly" %}`
`{{ another }}`
Result:
`it worked flawlessly`

Comment: @LunkRat It is recommended to use `~` to concatenate strings, rather than `+` (see https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/templates/#math)

Answer (score 94):

Nice shorthand for **Multiple variable assignments**

```
{% set label_cls, field_cls = "col-md-7", "col-md-3" %}
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to come close to answering the question?

Comment: @JohnRPerry But it is a nice addition to the accepted answer.

Answer (score 30):

Just Set it up like this

```
{% set active_link = recordtype -%}
```

Comment: Why specifically like so (the minus sign at the end but not at the beginning)? This would remove trailing but not leading whitespace, if I am not mistaken. To what end?

Comment: Its in the original question ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: The minus sign - appended to either the start or end of a statement (e.g. {%- <statement> -%}) tells Jinja to strip the new line that follows it. see https://www.webforefront.com/django/usebuiltinjinjastatements.html

Answer (score 20):

You can do this with the `set` tag. See the [official documentation](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/latest/templates/#assignments).

For example,

```
{% set foo = "bar" %}
{{ foo }}
```

outputs

```
bar
```

**Note**: there are scoping issues which means that variable values don’t persist between loop iterations, for example, if you want some output to be conditional on a comparison between previous and current loop values:

```
{# **DOES NOT WORK AS INTENDED** #}

{% set prev = 0 %}
{% for x in [1, 2, 3, 5] %}
{%- if prev != x - 1 %}⋮ (prev was {{ prev }})
{% endif -%}
{{ x }}
{%- set prev = x %}
{% endfor %}
```

prints

```
1
⋮ (prev was 0)
2
⋮ (prev was 0)
3
⋮ (prev was 0)
5
```

because the variable isn’t persisted. Instead you can use a mutable namespace wrapper:

```
{% set ns = namespace(prev=0) %}
{% for x in [1, 2, 3, 5] %}
{%- if ns.prev != x - 1 %}⋮ (ns.prev was {{ ns.prev }})
{% endif -%}
{{ x }}
{%- set ns.prev = x %}
{% endfor %}
```

which prints

```
1
2
3
⋮ (ns.prev was 3)
5
```

as intended.