# Substring at flask template

Tags: python, flask

I have a loop to show a list content in a flask template but I don't want to show the first character of the element , in this way works in python but not in flask

```
{%for file in files%}
        {% f= file['path'] %}
        <p> {{ f[1:] }}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

I get this error

```
TemplateSyntaxError: Encountered unknown tag 'f'. Jinja was looking for the following tags: 'endfor' or 'else'. The innermost block that needs to be closed is 'for'.
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to `set` variables if you wish to use them in that way. ([Documentation](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/templates/#assignments)).

That said— you should be able to just do `{{ file['path'][1:] }}` within your `for` loop.

Answer (score 3):

Duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3727045/set-variable-in-jinja).

You have to use the `{% set %}` template tag to assign variables within a jinja2 template:

```
{% for file in files %}
    {% set f = file['path'] %}
    <p>{{ f[1:] }}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: That being said, Doobeh has the right idea: just taking a slice of the dict value avoids this problem altogether.