# Create and access dict in Ansible playbook

Tags: ansible

I'm trying to set a variable in an Ansible playbook based on an existing variable's value which could be one of many different strings. It's basically a case/switch statement and this is the logic (with incorrect syntax):

```
if {{ existing_ansible_var }} == "string1"
  new_ansible_var = "a"
else if {{ existing_ansible_var }} == "string2"
  new_ansible_var = "b"
<...>
else
  new_ansible_var = ""
```

I can use a pretty slick technique with a dictionary that looks like this in Jinja:

```
{% set new_ansible_var = {"string1": "a", "string2": "b"}[existing_ansible_var] | default("") -%}
```

Can I use a similar dictionary construct to set a variable (`set_fact`) in a playbook?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Case statement for setting var in Ansible/Jinja2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30637054/case-statement-for-setting-var-in-ansible-jinja2)

Comment: You already asked virtually the same question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30637054/case-statement-for-setting-var-in-ansible-jinja2/30642550#30642550) four days ago and got a number of responses to that question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As described in the other [question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30644252/2753241), you can do it like this:

```
vars: 
   myDict: {"string1": "a", "string2": "b"}
   new_ansible_var: '{{myDict[existing_ansible_var | default("this key does not exist in the dict")] | default("") }}'
```