# if statement in Ansible with Jinja2 variables

Tags: python, jinja2, ansible

I have a variable file in my ansible setup called vars.yml, this file contains many variables in this format:

```
var1: 'val1'
var2: 'val2'
```

And it works fine, but I want to create new variables where the value is based on the value of another variable with an if statement - for example there could be:

```
"{% if var1|string() == 'val1' %} {% set var3 = 'val3' %} {% endif %}"
```

But this doesn't seem to work.

Comment: try `str` instead of `string`

Comment: That is not the issue, string() will still work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would that work for you?

```
{% set var3 = {"val1": "val3"}[var1] | default("") %}
```

It defines a dict, of values, which makes it quite easy to extend unlike a dozen if/else's.

```
{% set var3 = {"val1": "val3", "val2": "val4", "val5": "val6"}[var1] | default("") %}
```

You can make it even cleaner by defining it globally in your vars file

```
var1: 'val1'
var2: 'val2'
traslationTable:
  val1: val3
  val2: val4
  val5: val6
var3: "{{ traslationTable[var1] | default('') }}"
```

Also see my answer in https://stackoverflow.com/a/30644252/2753241

Comment: I tried this in my vars file:                          var1: 'val1'
  var3: "{% set var3 = {'val1': 'val3'}[var1] | default('') %}"                                            but when templating the replaced value is just ""

Comment: Don't use `set` in your vars file, just assign the value like this: `var3: "{{ {'val1': 'val3'}[var1] | default('') }}"`