# How to count authors in Pelican Blogs?

Tags: python, pelican

I was trying to make my blog show "Authors" instead of "Author" when there are more than 1 authors for the same article.

The solution (thanks to @Avaris) is to set `i = article.authors|count` and that can be used as follows

```
<div align="right">
          {% set i = article.authors|count %}
          {% if i != 1 %}
          Authors:<br>
          {% endif %}
          {% if i == 1 %}
          Author:<br>
          {% endif %}
          {% if article.authors %}
            {% for author in article.authors %}
              <a href="{{ SITEURL }}/{{ author.url }}">{{ author }}</a><br>
            {% endfor %}
          {% endif %}
        </div>
```

This is different to [Set variable in jinja](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3727045/set-variable-in-jinja) because in Pelican I cannot find a command like `lenght(authors)` to obtain a number to define a condition.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Set variable in jinja](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3727045/set-variable-in-jinja)

Comment: not really, because I read the documentation and the documentation does not say how to define `i = 1` where 1 is not constant but taken for the count of authors

Comment: You pretty much have it. You just need to do `{% set i = article.authors|count %}`.