Use multiple statements in the same Jinja block {% ... %}
Here is an example code from an SLS (salt stack) file, using Jinja:
{% set here = 'some-value' -%}
{%- set user = 'my_user' -%}
{%- set group = 'my_group' -%}

{%- set all_users = salt['user.list_users']() -%}
{%- if user in all_users -%}
{%- set usr_home = salt['user.info'](user).home -%}
{%- set prefix = 'some_prefix' ~ '_' ~ user %}

# This is just an example state
{{ prefix }}-dotvnc:
  file.directory:
    - name: {{ usr_home }}/.vnc
    - user: {{ user }}
    - group: {{ group }}
    - mode: '0700'

{% endif -%}

This looks very ugly, I would like to do something like this:
{% 
set here = 'some-value'
set user = 'my_user'
set group = 'my_group'

set all_users = salt['user.list_users']()
if user in all_users
  set usr_home = salt['user.info'](user).home
  set prefix = 'some_prefix' ~ '_' ~ user
%}

# This is just an example state
{{ prefix }}-dotvnc:
  file.directory:
    - name: {{ usr_home }}/.vnc
    - user: {{ user }}
    - group: {{ group }}
    - mode: '0700'

{% endif -%}

Multiple variables and commands cannot be avoided, this example shows a template that uses the home directory of a user from Jinja, but, the user may not exists when the template is rendered, and so its home directory may not exist.
While the first version works, it is very ugly, and hard to read.
Is there way to make this less cryptic?
This is not a duplicate of Code blocks in Jinja templates in salt, because dictionary lookups cannot be used in this case. E.g. the code is arbitrary.

Here is the syntax you are looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40177302/2123530

That question is very different. I think it does not answer my question.

The question is not really relevant, the specific answer I pointed to is. Multiple assignments in one expression block would use the unpack mechanism, so {% set here, user = 'some-value', 'my_user' %}, extend it with as much assignment as you’d like.

Maybe title of the question was not very clear. But my example shows that there are conditionals and loops; not just variable assignments. They cannot be "unpacked".

That part is just not possible. Jinja is a templating engine, it doesn’t allow multiple instructions in the same statement

This said, you could use line statement prefix, which would force you to prefix all Jinja line with a character, e.g.: https://docs.saltproject.io/en/latest/ref/configuration/master.html#jinja-sls-env

It's subjective anyway. I find the first version a lot clearer, as you can clearly see what is template commands and what isn't.

I have found that using the py renderer #!py to set complex variables and then just importing a whole dict into the sls file ends up being much cleaner and flexible for me than trying to use a lot of jinja.

See 11:17 of SaltStack Configuration Management Best Practices - SaltStack - SaltConf17 video on youtube https://youtu.be/xr8Zh1zvd7k?t=677

For simple variable definitions you could use YAML syntax within load_yaml or import_yaml. See this question.

One alternative syntax you could use is the line statement one — but if it is less cryptic or not is, off course, to your liking.
With it, your template could look like this:
% set user = 'my_user'
% set group = 'my_group'

% set all_users = salt['user.list_users']()
% if user in all_users
  % set usr_home = salt['user.info'](user).home
  % set prefix = 'some_prefix' ~ '_' ~ user

# This is just an example state
{{ prefix }}-dotvnc:
  file.directory:
    - name: {{ usr_home }}/.vnc
    - user: {{ user }}
    - group: {{ group }}
    - mode: '0700'
% endif

Which would render to something like
some_prefix_my_user-dotvnc:
  file.directory:
    - name: /home/my_user/.vnc
    - user: my_user
    - group: my_group
    - mode: '0700'


This possibility is offered via the parameters line_statement_prefix and line_comment_prefix.

In SaltStack, this can be configured in the Salt configurations files, under the keys jinja_env and jinja_sls_env.
E.g.:
jinja_sls_env:
  line_statement_prefix: '%'
  line_comment_prefix: '#'


In an Ansible template, this can be passed as the first line of the template:
#jinja2:line_statement_prefix: '%', line_comment_prefix: '#'
% set user = 'my_user'
# ... the rest of the template goes here


In a Python / Jinja project, this would be configured via parameters set at the environment initialisation.
from jinja2 import Environment, PackageLoader, select_autoescape
env = Environment(
    loader=PackageLoader("yourapp"),
    line_statement_prefix='%', 
    line_comment_prefix='#'
)




No, the first example code you provided is just the way Jinja works.

I'll wait some before I accept; others might have a suggestion.
